# Named types produce less useful information in my IDE

Tags: typescript, intellisense

I am working on a library and I'm hoping to provide contextual help to my users directly in their IDE thanks to Typescript.

However, it seems I get less useful information when I name my types as opposed to describing them fully every time.

Here is a contrived example implemented twice, once with named types and the other with full type descriptions everywhere, to illustrate my problem:

1. *Named types*

```
export type ComplexNumber = {
  r: number,
  i: number
}

export default function addComplexNumbers (
  a: ComplexNumber,
  b: ComplexNumber
): ComplexNumber {
  return { r: a.r + b.r, i: a.i + b.i }
}
```

With this version, if I start writing `addComplexNumbers(`, my IDE (VS Code) will give me the type information for the function parameters and return values like this:

```
addComplexNumbers(a: ComplexNumber, b: ComplexNumber): ComplexNumber
```

This is correct, but doesn't help me provide correct parameters for `a` and `b`. Instead, I'm left guessing how to make something compatible with a `ComplexNumber`. I could try `new ComplexNumber` or an object with keys like `real` and `imaginary`, but in both cases I would be wrong.

Compare with the version below:

*Full type description everywhere*

```
export default function addComplexNumbers (
  a: { r: number, i: number },
  b: { r: number, i: number }
): { r: number, i: number } {
  return { r: a.r + b.r, i: a.i + b.i }
}
```

In this case I get more help once I start typing `addComplexNumbers(`:

```
addComplexNumbers(a: { r: number; i: number; }, b: { r: number; i: number; }): { r: number; i: number; }
```

As you can see, the second version provides much more helpful information than the first.

However, the second method also involves more repeated code and therefore isn't as easy to maintain.

***My Question***:

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, avoiding repeated code, keeping a single source of truth for my types, and also providing more helpful information to the user?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand... If you use `addComplexNumbers({});` and prompt for autocomplete inside the braces, it'll show you `r` and `i`...

Comment: Additionally, anyone who wonders what to do should probably use their IDE's "go to definition" or "go to references" functionality to get to the type definition, and if they can't do that for `ComplexNumber` they are likely to be mystified by all the type definitions that are native to TypeScript and you probably shouldn't worry about them because your code is the least of their problems.  I guess I'm having a hard time envisioning the sort of user that benefits from this; could you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: @vr. When I type in the `{`, I do not get any more info automatically. How would I prompt for autocomplete inside the braces (using VS Code)?

Comment: @jcalz "go to definition" works for this, but it's not as immediate as what I get with my second option. With the second option, I get what I need straight away. With my first option, I have to move away from the parameters and back to the function name, then right click, then go to definition, and from there go to definition again on the parameter. By this point, I have my type info, but now I'm in a completely different file (potentially). Basically I'm just trying to make things easier…

Comment: @vi. I just found Ctrl+Space for prompting VS Code for auto-completion. This actually pretty much solves my issue, so thanks for bringing me back down to Earth. Basically, my real problem was not knowing how my editor works.

Comment: @vi. Actually, I'm still finding it very much less easy to use. First, the developer has to think of trying an empty object and using `ctrl+space`, and even then, the valid expected properties appear alongside other unrelated suggestions (depending on your editor and config, in my case I get code snippets from VS Code…